# Use of function.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

what is the use of `function.php` in wordpress?

```
   <?php 
function amazing_script_equeue(){wp_enqueue_style('customstyle',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/awsomew.css',array( ),'1.0.0','all');}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','amazing_script_equeue');
```

what does the above code do when the page loads?

Answer (score 1):

The [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) puts it nicely:

> One way to change the default behaviors of WordPress is using a file
>   named functions.php. It goes in your Theme's folder.
>
> The functions file behaves like a WordPress Plugin, adding features
>   and functionality to a WordPress site. You can use it to call
>   functions, both PHP and built-in WordPress, and to define your own
>   functions. You can produce the same results by adding code to a
>   WordPress Plugin or through the WordPress Theme functions file.

The code in question is a function that is being called at runtime, which is pulling a file called `/css/awsomew.css` into the themes frontend. This file is located at `...wp-content/your-theme-name/css/awsomew.css`. For more information on the `wp_enqueue_style()` function, see the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Theme functions.php behaves like a plugin that runs inside the theme file, almost all code you'll find on plugins will also run when added on functions.php file,

the above functions you have provided will add this stylesheet below inside your head tag,

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='customstyle' href='yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/themename/css/awsomew.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='all' />`